# Equivalent of "git reset --hard" with SVN

Tags: svn

I would like to revert my SVN **central** repository, not a working copy, from revision M to revision N ( M > N ), like a git reset --hard

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**

the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24500425/520162) seems to be a better solution than the one proposed by me. Check that one!

---

On the client, it's simple:

```
svn checkout -r <revision> url://path/to/repo
```

should do it.

If you're on the server (like your edited question says), it depends what you want to achieve.

---

If you want to throw away all revisions after `N`, do a

```
svnadmin dump -r1:N yourrepo > repo.dump
```

then, delete the old repo and create a new one

```
svnadmin create newrepo
svnadmin load newrepo < repo.dump
```

---

If you want to keep your repo, check out `N` on a client and commit to the server, so that `N` is the latest state.

---

Third one: set up a branch starting from `N` and work on that one.

Comment: @Quentin: which way did you use?

Comment: It is some better the solution in the next answer ```svn revert --recursive . ```

Answer (score 49):

Here you go.

```
svn revert --recursive .
```

Comment: This seems preferable to the selected answer. Easier to remember the command and no digging for the repo URL).

Comment: svn revert --recursive didn't work for the branch conflict. I was able to fix it with svn checkout.